# How do I remove something from an array list when looping through it in java?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I have an arraylist like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And let's say the values inside are like:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

So I'm looping through and I want to remove values from the arraylist while I'm looping through:

```
for(int i=0; i<numbers.size();i++){
    if(numbers.get(i)>2){
    numbers.remove(i);
    }
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: I would consider creating a new list (copy) containing only the wanted values. It is so much safer. Of course, unless the list is very, very huge.

Comment: I'd say the exact opposite: removing elements becomes much less efficient on huge lists;  it depends on n^2 while creating a list is n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call numbers.remove(i) and then decrement i to follow the change in the position within the list: `numbers.remove(i); i--;`.

If you use iterators, foreach or the : operator you can't remove values, because they use unmodifiable lists.

If you have a simple way of determining whether a number should be removed, you can use `numbers.removeIf((number)->number>2)` (like the problem in your example).

Comment: thank you so much! that i--; call was genius! I'm glad I posted a new question. thanks for posting an answer (a different and much better one) instead of referring me to the other one